# Proof 7.3 from the PCI DSS standard

Tags: pci-dss

> 7.3 Examine documentation interview personnel to verify that security policies and operational procedures for restricting access to cardholder data are:
>   · Documented,
>   · In use, and
>   · Known to all affected parties.

As a service provider providing monitoring for customer on their networks and datacenter locations, I wonder how I can proof this rather verbal question for my `PCI DSS` assessment validation.

The company has in place security information and test to validate that all employees has received information how to handle sensitive data such as credit card information and leakage, etc.

But how do I make a proof of the above quote? 
How do I proof that by monitor their network and systems, that we don't log any kind of credit card information and cardholder data?

Comment: To clarify- the question is about how to provide proof to a customer, or to an auditor?

Comment: I thank you for your answer Jonah, it's for an auditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audience for that guidance is QSAs- Qualified Security Assessors- whose job it is to appear onsite, examine documentation, interview personnel, and perform other audit-related activities to ensure they are comfortable issuing a reporting indicating the company is PCI compliant.

In terms of the specific proof- the auditor will decide what evidence to consider- whatever documentation you have, configuration, log files- in determining whether you meet the standards. They should provide some direction to you regarding the specific pieces of evidence they need to see.

Higher level, as a service provider whose customers have to be PCI compliant and whose engagement with those customers exposes systems you control to your customers card data environments, you have to have your own PCI compliance documentation- either your own Report on Compliance provided by an auditor, or, should your customer transaction levels be low enough, a Service Provider Self Assessment Questionnaire. That documentation gets provided to customers as evidence when they go through their own PCI audits. Customers should not be coming to you for answers on specific questions on their own compliance.